# PyQt QTableWidget signal emitted when selecting no rows

Tags: python, events, pyqt, selection, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` in *pyQt* with single row selection set.  I am connecting `itemSelectionChanged` to call my row selection function and take action on the selected row.  I would also like to detect when the user selects inside the `QTableWidget`, but selects the empty space (no row is selected), so that I can deselect any selected row.  Similar to how "windows explorer" works with file selections.

What signal is triggered when selecting the blank area inside a `QTableWidget`?  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I don't understand...  

With a selected table row, clicking outside, the row is deselected automatically.

Comment: aha... I am using selectionmethod = singleselection instead of extendedselection.  It appears to work if I change to extendedselection, but I will need to manually limit selected rows to 1...

Comment: Maybe you want to set   
    `table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)`   
too?

Answer (score 3):

Check mouse-press events to see if the clicked item is `None`:

```
class Table(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.itemAt(event.pos()) is None:
            self.clearSelection()
        QtGui.QTableWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

Or if you can't subclass, use an event-filter:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.table.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
            source is self.table.viewport() and
            self.table.itemAt(event.pos()) is None):
            self.table.clearSelection()
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.